# Unable to get relevant information from Google People API through Access Token after authentication

Tags: react-native, google-people-api

I am trying to add sign-in functionality to my react-native application. I have implemented google auth through AppAuth to obtain an access token and now I want to obtain the user's email

I have tried different URLs but all of them return gibberish. I have created a project for my app in google and have enabled the People API and done all the credential settings

```
_handlePressAsync = async () => {
    config = {
      issuer: 'https://accounts.google.com',
      clientId: GOOGLE_APP_ID,
      scopes: ['profile','email'],
  }
    let result = await AppAuth.authAsync(config);
    this.setState({ result });
    console.debug(result);
    //let userInfo = await fetch('https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me', {headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${result.accessToken}` }});
    //let userInfo = await     fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token=${result.accessToken}`);
    console.debug('-------------USER INFO-------------')
    console.debug(userInfo);
  };
```

There are 2 `let userInfo = ...` lines, I tried them one at a time.

The first one returns:

```
Response {
  "_bodyBlob": Blob {
    "_data": Object {
      "blobId": "ca99a1a3-8a69-443e-aa41-6d0507e1d0e0",
      "offset": 0,
      "size": 251,
    },
  },
  "_bodyInit": Blob {
    "_data": Object {
      "blobId": "ca99a1a3-8a69-443e-aa41-6d0507e1d0e0",
      "offset": 0,
      "size": 251,
    },
  },
  "headers": Headers {
    "map": Object {
      "alt-svc": "quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43,39\"",
      "cache-control": "public, max-age=0",
      "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      "date": "Sun, 08 Sep 2019 06:00:36 GMT",
      "server": "ESF",
      "vary": "Referer",
      "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
      "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
      "x-xss-protection": "0",
    },
  },
  "ok": false,
  "status": 400,
  "statusText": undefined,
  "type": "default",
  "url": "https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me",
}
```

while the second one returns:

```
Response {
  "_bodyBlob": Blob {
    "_data": Object {
      "blobId": "318cb3ab-ae66-48d7-a5f2-302cd0d25278",
      "offset": 0,
      "size": 323,
    },
  },
  "_bodyInit": Blob {
    "_data": Object {
      "blobId": "318cb3ab-ae66-48d7-a5f2-302cd0d25278",
      "offset": 0,
      "size": 323,
    },
  },
  "headers": Headers {
    "map": Object {
      "alt-svc": "quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43,39\"",
      "cache-control": "public, max-age=0",
      "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      "date": "Sun, 08 Sep 2019 06:04:53 GMT",
      "expires": "Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT",
      "server": "ESF",
      "vary": "Referer",
      "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
      "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
      "x-xss-protection": "0",
    },
  },
  "ok": true,
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": undefined,
  "type": "default",
  "url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token=ya29.Glt9B43nkzGHkWAcTmplkcO2geSFHI8cxSBVvnDwCbbSUPnM79Xx7zxwOw8CzhhGZfxmGS9mEKCzjPVeRFj3hruTMinkkjkh6PqhCvr-Hy9sQtJEEAxSkgwrkjTY",
}
```